# Merge two arrays by key but mantain the key of the first in PHP, array_combine fails

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to combine two arrays but mantaining the key of the first.

I've this data:

```
$days = array(
    1 => array("name" => "Monday"),
    2 => array("name" => "Tuesday"),
    3 => ...
    30 => array("name" => "Sunday"),
);
```

And another one with the clicks:

```
$clics = array(
    2 => array("clicks" => 4),
    10 => array("clicks" => 2),
);
```

My desired array is:

```
$final = array(
    1 => array("name" => "Monday"),
    2 => array("name" => "Tuesday", "clicks" => 4),
    3 => ... 
    4 =>
    5 => 
    ...
    10 => array("name" => "Tuesday", "clicks" => 2),
    ..
    30 => array("name" => "Sunday"),
);
```

In the second array if there is no click the index doesn't exists. I have tried array_combine but needs to have the same key and array_merge fails to.

What option I have?

Thank you in advance

Comment: please write your desired array. as your question is not clear.

Comment: @stereofrog: if I can do it wihout using foreach, better.

Comment: is anything wrong with for/foreach?

Comment: I think you should use a foreach loop, as this is a complicated thing,  so you can pick up the clic by using same id to merge them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [array_merge_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) function on PHP.net. Also, check out the comments there to seek if one of those functions are providing the desired array (I.E. [comment #104145](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#104145) and [comment #102379](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#102379)

Also, please note that with the use of a foreach, you are sure to have the desired array eventually. Are there any specific reasons why you don't want, or cannot use foreach?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any way to do this with out a loop, but with a loop it's easy:

```
function merge_your_arrays ($days, $clicks) {
  foreach ($days as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($clicks[$k])) {
      $days[$k] = array_merge($days[$k],$clicks[$k]);
    }
  }
  return $days;
}

$final = merge_your_arrays($days, $clicks);
```